# Iterate over folders in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Scenario: a folder containing other folders

```
Folder\
  Sample Folder 01\
  Sample Folder 02\
  .....
```

I need to run the follow command to each SampleFolderxx:

```
7z a -tzip "Sample Folder xx".cbz "Sample Folder xx"\ -mx0
```

How could I do a batch file to read each folder name in `Folder\` and execute the command above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a for loop. Put the below lines into a .bat file, `cd` to "Folder", paste the batch file there and run it.

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in (`dir /b /ad-h`) do (
    7z a -tzip "%%F".cbz "%%F"\ -mx0
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
Now you are my best friend :) @adarshr